# Unable to get third subcollection in firestore react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**Unable to get third Sub-collection in Firestore with react native.
the code i m trying given below.**

```
const db = Firebase.firestore();
 const query= db.collection('Subject').doc('Biology')
 .collection('Topic').doc('Animal Anatomy and Physiology')
 .collection('Sub-topic').doc('ATP')
   query.get()
   .then(snapshot => { 
     console.log('snapshot ',snapshot.data())    // undefined  })
```

Comment: Your code looks correct! Can we see a preview of your Firestore document structure? At quick glance, 'cells' is lowercase, which is different from your other docs?

Comment: this is the path i want to access              /Subject/Biology/Topic/Animal Anatomy and Physiology/Sub-topic /ATP

Comment: i find a solution actually  in the doc their is space between keywords so firestore return undefined, If we remove space between keyword from doc() then it read the data.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**In the firestore doc dont  make spaces between the doc make one word it will work fine**

```
const db = Firebase.firestore();
     const query= db.collection('Subject').doc('Biology')
     .collection('Topic')
   .doc('AnimalAnatomyandPhysiology') // Remove space it will work chnge into database also
     .collection('Sub-topic').doc('ATP')
       query.get()
       .then(snapshot => { 
         console.log('snapshot ',snapshot.data()) // data  })
```